# Is the concept of focus applicable to action items of ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

We know that a button of Android can request focus so that it is highlighted.  The action items on an ActionBar (e.g. the search and Google Play icons in the following figure) are quite similar to buttons. I am wondering they can also obtain focus.

[image]